# Insert select auto increment bug

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, auto-increment

I need some help with my SQL code:

`insert into '.$type.' select * from ' .$type.' where effective_id = '.$id`

But I get error with this code.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into actionplan select * from actionplan where effective_id = 3)
```

Any ideas how to skip id column? I have to use this code on several tables. So I can't write all columns.

Comment: What DBMS? This varies with the specific SQL product.

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the error message

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking "how do I use `select *` but not exclude one of the columns?`

Sorry, that's not what `select *` means. It means get *all* the columns. There is no syntax in SQL for `select *-except-for-id`.

If you want all the columns except for one, then you must spell out all the columns you do want.

```
$sql = "insert into $type (id, col1, col2, col3) 
  select NULL, col1, col2, col3 from $type where effective_id = $id";
```